# Ghost blog via helm chart - How to have different logo based on dark or light?

Tags: ghost-blog

I have a ghost blog installed via the helm chart.

I installed the theme: https://github.com/godofredoninja/simply

I am trying to understand how to show a different logo image (light) when the switch is clicked to change to dark/light.

Is there some general way to do this with ghost, and do you need to port into the pod to change files or can it be done from the settings?

Answer (score 0):

You can not achieve this by using your publication logo. You should change this in the theme and then upload the theme to your ghost blog.
You can upload a theme by going in the `design` -> `upload a theme`. If you need more help on this topic visit [here](https://codebulbs.com).

Comment: I can change the logo in the theme, but I do not know what to check for to detect if the theme is set to dark or light.

Comment: You should work on your CSS skills first. If you need more help connect on the link I have shared in answer.